# Sony Action Camera Wowza Support

Tags: sony-camera-api

We would like to use the Sony Action game to stream with our CDN. Is it possible to stream to a service other than Ustream. In particular our services uses Wowza which is a common internet streaming service.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's definitely possible! I'm streaming with my Sony ILCE-QX1 to my own Streaming Server over RTMP, so Wowza is also possible. It's possible to stream from all these Cameras(https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/) to any Streaming Server. I have also a working Live Stream from the new  Gopro4 ;)